# Tire does not search partial keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, tire

How to use wildcard in tire queries.
temporally i am using * in search query itself,but it is increasing its execution time.
Is there any other way??
i am newbie & not using json methods at all to config my elascticsearch.

here is my code.

models/movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks
    mapping do
        indexes :title,boost: 10
        indexes :year
        indexes :author
    end
    def self.search(params)
        #binding.pry
        tire.search(load: true) do |s|
            s.query {string "*#{params[:query]}*"} if params[:query].present?
            s.filter :range,year: {lte: 2004}
        end
    end
end
```

controller/search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if(params[:query]).present?
    @results=Movie.search(params)
    else
    @results=[]
    end
  end
end
```

view/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Search#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/search/index.html.erb</p>


    <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
    <% if @results %>
    <% @results.each do |fetchresults| %>
    <%= fetchresults.title %> 
    <%= fetchresults.year %>
    <%= fetchresults.author %><br/>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

for eg. i have paris in my database & when i am searching for "aris" it should show the paris in search results,by default it is not showing any results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "*like*", as the following:

let's suppose that you *movie* table has an attribute called *name*

@results=Movie.where("name like ?", "aris")

Comment: Hey Soul,i am asking specifically for tire,not for normal rails query.